# I have an old (1996) felony conviction in Japan and am barred from visiting: Can I transit through there?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, japan, drugs

In 1996 I was convicted of felony importation of 23 grams of pot. I served 23 days in jail and paid a $11000 fine and had 30 days to leave the country. In 2018 I tried to go back on my way to China and Vietnam. I was detained at the Narita airport, held incommunicado for 18 hours, and put on the same plane I came in on, back to Portland, against my will.

I can never visit Japan again. But, can I transit through there, on my way to Hanoi, without getting jerked out of line and being sent back again? 
We're scheduled to leave on the 15th of April, so time is of the essence on this answer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've already been unable to transit through Japan once.  Why do you think it might have changed?  Because of the passage of time?  That was only two years ago.

Comment: Was 2018 also a transit, or an attempted visit?

Comment: I'd say the best option would be to contact the nearest Japanese consulate. Or avoid Japan altogether, there are probably many other ways to get to Hanoi. Though in the upcoming 30 days, there are great chances that any form of international travel could become very difficult altogether.

Comment: I've done some web searches, and "landing" seems to be prohibited with a drug conviction, which does not look good for transit. I agree with @jcaron.

Comment: Isn’t applying for a transit visa the only way to know for sure? Although it seems highly unlikely it would be approved.

Comment: Why don't you just transit through a different country? A little more money or travel time seem way less risky than dealing with country that really doesn't want you

Answer (score 17):

I posted the question and have since heard from the Japanese Immigration Bureau: the answer is no, if you've been convicted of a felony you cannot land in Japan or transit through it.

Comment: You should probably [accept](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer.

Comment: Is it a permanent ban?